# Custom SurfaceView causing NoSuchMethodException

Tags: android, xml, exception, constructor, custom-view

I have a custom View extending SurfaceView. The XML layout is

```
<com.myPackage.MyCustomView
  android:id="@+id/mycview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

The class is :

```
public class MyCustomView extends SurfaceView{

public float[] xpositions;
public float[] ypositions;
public String[] units;


public MyCustomView(Context context, float[] xpos, float[] ypos,String[] u) {
    super(context);
    xpositions=xpos;
    ypositions =ypos;
    units=u;


     }
}
```

In the context Activity for this method, I have the following line

```
MyCustomView mv = (MyCustomView)findViewById(R.id.mycview);
```

The Logcat output has the following

```
01-30 01:51:12.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4934): Caused by:  java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:MyCustomView(Context,AttributeSet) 
01-30 01:51:12.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4934):    at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:674) 
01-30 01:51:12.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:486) 
01-30 01:51:12.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:475)
```

For some reason, my constructor is causing above exception. I would appreciate any help finding what is wrong with the code.

UPDATE:
I changed the constructor to add AttributeSet and in my activity wrote the following:

```
 XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.id.mycview);
 AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);


 MyCustomView cv = new MyCustomView(this,attributes,xx,yy,uu);
              cv = (MyCustomView)findViewById(R.id.mycview);
```

But I get the same logcat output.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't have the correct constructor MyCustomView(Context,AttributeSet)

You must create the following constructors if you want to inflate views, and create new one in code.
use `initYourStuff()` to init your stuff ;) , you can also parametrize them of course...

```
public MyCustomView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    initYourStuff();

}

public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    initYourStuff();
}

public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
    initYourStuff();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did as you said, see my update. I'm still getting the same exception

Comment: try static inner class.