# Inflating a Generic/Templated Custom View

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

Is it possible to inflate a custom/subclassed view that is templated ?

That is, can the following be inflated:

```
public class TextViewT<T> : TextView
{
    List<T> _list;

    public TextViewT(Context context) : base(context) { }
    public TextViewT(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes) : base(context, attributes) { }
}
```

If so, what is the syntax in the layout file for such a type ?

Specifically, how would the absolute class name `app.droid.views.custom.TextViewT` appear ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<app.views.custom.TextViewT
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/text_view_t"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

I get the following exception when attempting to do so:

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'App.Droid.Views.Custom.TextViewT, App.Droid, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
at System.Type.GetType (string,bool) <0x00027>
at Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00057>
at (wrapper native-to-managed) Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x0006f>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr_JValue[] (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) <0x000cb>
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) <0x00067>
at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (int) <0x001d7>
at App.Droid.Views.CalendarView.Render () <0x00073>
at MonoCross.Droid.MXActivityView`1<App.ViewModels.CalendarVM>.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x00243>
at App.Droid.Views.CalendarView.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x0001b>
at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00057>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.cb51fcb8-c099-4fce-b266-642090f4d778 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00043>
```

Thank you.

Comment: According to http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/limitations generics can only be created from managed (.net) code. So if the inflation process is done in native Java code (which it probably is), then no dice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008426/adding-a-custom-view-to-xml-but-with-a-generic-type

Comment: It is actually possible to use Java generics in your XML layouts using a certain Gradle plugin, explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26766254/1331240

Answer (score 0):

Well, since it isn't possible in raw android, then it's certainly not possible in Xamarin.Android:

[Adding a custom view to XML... but with a GENERIC-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008426/adding-a-custom-view-to-xml-but-with-a-generic-type)